# Avatar not picked up

Tags: bug, profile-page

I'm a long time user of other StackExchange sites and recently signed up with fitness. For a change I succeed in using the right way to sign up to get my accounts linked and all the information (bio and stuff) shows up in my fitness profile. But my avatar is some generic icon.

I have no problem uploading the proper avatar icon, but I wonder if this is a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Just choose Gravatar from your user profile. Recent work that deals with when we do / do not request profile images from OAuth providers (Facebook / Google +) might have introduced a quirk where identicon is the default *even if you have an established profile on other sites*, which I do not believe was intentional.

If you go to your profile page and just select gravatar, or your custom image (if you have one), it will go back to normal.

Sorry about the confusion!